# jquery getScript data

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
$.getScript("javascriptfile.js", function(data ){


   alert("Script loaded and executed."+data);


});
</script>
```

data return undefined. I want to get the response data or content of javascriptfile.js

tested below not working

```
$.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js", function(data){


   alert("Script loaded and executed."+data);


});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a problem

```
//This one will NOT work
$.getScript("http://jquerymobile.com/branches/popup-widget/js/", 
        function (data) {
               alert("Script loaded and executed." + data);
});

//This one will work
$.getScript("js/jquery.min.js", 
        function (data) {
               alert("Script loaded and executed." + data);
});
```

`$.getScript()` doesn't provide content of the script file if you are making a cross origin request outside of your domain.

Comment: This caused me a whole lot of heartache! upvoted

Answer (score 2):

Kindly run this and reply with the exception message, so I can follow up with you:

```
$.getScript("javascriptfile.js")
.done(function(script, textStatus) {
    alert(textStatus);
})
.fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    alert(exception);
});
```

Comment: i do not want textstatus, i want the entire response (entire content of response)

Comment: @Liew, i posted latest code. result is undefined

Comment: that is just sample . already included jquery in <script> before call this .

Answer (score 0):

i don't know why you'd want the content of the file since getScript executes it after loading it & the call back is just a callback to if necesary call functions/plugins/whatever you have just loaded;
if you want content of a file do `$.get` instead but anyway

```
do 
function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    console.log(data); //data returned
    console.log(textStatus); //success
    console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
    console.log('Load was performed.');
  });
```

to spot the "problem" if any (from http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

Comment: does not work. i already tried this before post

Comment: i didn't write it would work but that it would narrow down the problem, paste your console results (in fact me using with .done & the cachedscript example provided in the link given; if any error a typo/incorrect url...